# Left Join without duplicate values from the left table when multiple values in right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The Following query brings back a list of IDs and a list of times. It's bringing back multimple from the Left table because it appears multiple in the right table.

It Currently brings back this:

[image]

I want it to bring back the minimum value from the right table for each ID in the left table.

Any help appreciated!

```
set language british 
SELECT dbo.Employee.EmployeeID, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, ClockTemp.ClockTime, 108), 1, 5) as ClockTime
FROM  dbo.Employee LEFT JOIN 
(
    Select [ClockID]
      ,[EmployeeID]
      ,[ClockTypeID]
      ,[ClockDate]
      ,[ClockTime] 
    FROM dbo.Clock 
    WHERE dbo.Clock.ClockDate = DATEADD(DD, 0, CAST('07-11-2016' AS DATE)) AND Clock.ClockTypeID=1
) As ClockTemp
ON dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = ClockTemp.EmployeeID
ORDER BY dbo.Employee.EmployeeID,clocktemp.ClockTime
```

Comment: Have you tried a GROUP BY in the sub-query?

Comment: Tried just adding 
GROUP BY [ClockTime],[ClockID],[EmployeeID],[ClockTypeID],[ClockDate] 
Underneath the WHERE but can't get it to work...

Comment: You can also try `SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Employee.EmployeeID,.....`

Comment: Tried that, comes back with "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified." -- 
So I added ClockTime to the select statement - but it just brought back the same as without the DISTINCT

Comment: Can you update your query as you make changes? It would help.

Comment: Not actually making the changes - just putting them in and reverting them if they don't work. Will try the responses shortly and see if any of them work. Thanks for the help so far everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this query would work for you. You do not need to order by Clocktime as the minimum value will be brought through from the MIN aggregate.

I would also change the Clocktime field to TIME if you are using SQL 2008 so that you can avoid the substring convert.

```
set language british 
SELECT dbo.Employee.EmployeeID, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, MIN(ClockTemp.ClockTime), 108), 1, 5) as ClockTime
FROM  dbo.Employee LEFT JOIN 
(
    Select [ClockID]
      ,[EmployeeID]
      ,[ClockTypeID]
      ,[ClockDate]
      ,[ClockTime] 
    FROM dbo.Clock 
    WHERE dbo.Clock.ClockDate = DATEADD(DD, 0, CAST('07-11-2016' AS DATE)) AND Clock.ClockTypeID=1
) As ClockTemp
ON dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = ClockTemp.EmployeeID
GROUP BY dbo.Employee.EmployeeID
ORDER BY dbo.Employee.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Worked great straight off the bat, didn't even have to edit anything to make it work in my DB. Thanks!

Comment: @hero9989: Thanks for accepting my answer. Have a lovely day

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
WITH minClockTimeCTE AS (
  SELECT EmployeeID, min(ClockTime) as ClockTime
  FROM ClockTemp
  GROUP BY EmployeeID
)
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, minClockTimeCTE.ClockTime
FROM Employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN minClockTimeCTE 
  ON Employee.EmployeeID = minClockTimeCTE.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the left join to an outer apply top 1:

```
SELECT dbo.Employee.EmployeeID, 
  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, ClockTemp.ClockTime, 108), 1, 5) as ClockTime
FROM  dbo.Employee 
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 [ClockID]
        ,[EmployeeID]
        ,[ClockTypeID]
        ,[ClockDate]
        ,[ClockTime] 
    FROM dbo.Clock 
    WHERE dbo.Clock.ClockDate = DATEADD(DD, 0, CAST('07-11-2016' AS DATE)) 
        AND Clock.ClockTypeID=1
        AND dbo.Employee.EmployeeID = ClockTemp.EmployeeID
    ORDER BY ClockTime
) As ClockTemp
ORDER BY dbo.Employee.EmployeeID,clocktemp.ClockTime
```